# Trying to access to another internal factory function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to know if it's possible to use a function inside factory in other factory function and how. I tried but it said that the function doesn't essists. For example, I have this factory:

```
    .factory("SyncService", function($q, $http, ...){
    return {
       function1: function(){
               //Do function1 things
               },
       function2: function(){
               //Here I want to call function1
               }
           }
    }
```

So in this example, it is posible to call function1 inside function2?

Comment: Thank you to everyone. You all helped me but I mark just one of your answers as my favorite although I like them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do by re-structuring the way you code your service.. here is a best practice for you:

```
.factory("SyncService", function($q, $http, ...){

    var fun = function(){
               //Do function1 things
               };
    var anotherFun = function(){
                fun();
               };
    var service {
        function1: fun ,
       function2: anotherFun
           }
    };

    return service;  

}
```

Comment: The problem is that the function **fun** must be called also outside. In order to to that I should call it like: **SyncService.function1** ???
Sorry if my question is basic but I don't understand very good these factory functions :P

Comment: yes, from the controller you will call `SyncService.function1()`

Comment: This is the recommended way : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#factories

Answer (score 1):

You can use
this.function1();

```
.factory("SyncService", function($q, $http, ...){
    return {
       function1: function(){
               //Do function1 things
               },
       function2: function(){
                this.function1();
               }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly call the factory function from another factory function.

Index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="1.0.0-alpha.5" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.5/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="factory.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Facotory.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .factory('myFactory',function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.myFunction1 = function(){
      this.myFunction2();
    }
    obj.myFunction2 = function(){
            alert("HEY!");
    }    

    return obj;

  });
```

Controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp')

  .controller('myCtrl',function($scope,myFactory){

    myFactory.myFunction1();

  })
```

Here is the working plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/SZV7i97WJHw7LDhIjyzW?p=preview